# Can't read explanations on iPad

Tags: bug, status-completed

Explanations cannot be read on iPad. Selecting them doesn't make them visible. Please implement that they become visible after a tap!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108090/180276. You could also just use the iOS app.

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, yes this is a duplicate then. The iOS app isn't for iPad though.

Comment: To play Devil's advocate, you could dump your iPad and get an Android tablet where everything just works ;)

Comment: [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site)

Answer (score -3):

This question is about spoilers that explain answers to some [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) questions.

This is an example of a spoiler:

> Snape kills Luke Skywalker's father! Also, the Titanic hits the Hindenburg!

Firefox for Android works. If I tap the spoiler, the text appears. If I then tap somewhere else, the text disappears.

Comment: This answer is not an answer, unless your answer is to use Firefox for Android on iPad, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Firefox might not be the only browser where one may tap to reveal spoiler. Because the question does not include a spoiler, I will leave my spoiler here in case some iPad user finds a way to reveal it.